# Is it appropriate to mention how long you've been applying at the same company?

Tags: job-search, applications

In my city there's this large company employing several thousand people, at which I've already worked before during a small period, and where I'd really like to be employed again for a number of reasons.  Since it's a renowned place, it attracts between 300 and 600 applicants for every single job opening they post.

I've quite good qualifications and experience, and I've been applying for a large number of jobs there in the last ten years (*).  I've mixed feeling as whether I should mention this in my job applications, or it would be better to leave it out, and whether it would make any difference.  Would that sound as very motivated to work at the company (making me stand out among the other candidates), or just as desperate/pathetic?

(*) So far I managed just to obtain a 1-year contract, long time ago.

Comment: Do you still have the contact information for the person you worked for previously at the company?  Always good to speak with someone on the inside if you get a opportunity.

Comment: Yes, and I know several other people inside, but they have a standardized recruitment process.  All jobs are advertised publicly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is a very important fact for them to know, so I wouldn't mention it. Either they already know that fact because they remember you as a potential recruit, either they don't and recalling them you applied several times may make them think they had reasons not to hire you before.

Instead, use your knowledge of the company for a good, targetted cover letter. Insist on your motivation and explain **why** you applied several times before.

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be foolish.  If I were the HR person and you shared that with me, the first thing I'd do is to figure out why you kept being disqualified.  Just keep that information to yourself.

Answer (score 2):

In resumes you keep to relevant work experience.  If that 1-year contract is relevant to the post you are applying to and you then include it.  Including it will not make it appear that you are motivated nor would it make you appear pathetic.  From their eyes it is just work experience.

If you really want this position, the best thing you can do is make sure your resume/CV is well polished and have several other people you trust review it.  If there is anything in it that would make you look desperate hopefully they would notice it and point it out to you.

Comment: That's not what I was asking, in fact. My question was unclear; I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

In a Danish context, one would have to include that you have worked there before as it obviously is extremely relevant to the current position. You need not mention that you have applied on numerous occasions.

If the contract went well, I see no reason to not include the experience. It shows they were willing to hire you before and you were of value to them.

Even if your past experience at the company was negative, you would need to include it, as having the company find out that you hadn't mentioned this previous experience probably would create an awkward situation and possibly put you out of the running.

Not mentioning having applied on numerous occasions should not carry a similar penalty, as applying for (but not getting) a job by most would be considered a non-event.

Comment: That's not what I was asking, in fact. My question was unclear; I've edited it.